# Validate database entries at startup of SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have multiple `@Service` implementations of an interface. Which of these implementations is used at runtime for any given request is configured in a databse.
Something like this:

| Value | Service Bean |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | ServiceA |
| World | ServiceB |
| Foo | ServiceA |
| Bar | ServiceC |

The correct bean is then retrieved using the application context and the defined Service Bean Name from the database. However it could be possible that a Service Bean is mentioned in the database that does not exist in the application context. I'd rather detect this during startup than at runtime.

This question basically boils down to how you add your own validation to the spring boot startup process or what's the best practice? I tried throwing an Exception when creating the bean, that deals with the mapping of values to Service Beans, and handling it with my own `FailureAnalyzer`. But the `FailureAnalyzer` never gets called because due to the missing bean an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` is also thrown and causes the application to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I'm happy with.

1. I did not register my `FailureAnalyzer` in my resource folder in the `META-INF/spring.factories` file.
2. As described in the question throwing my `Exception` during bean creation caused an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. So instead I used an `ApplicationListener` and perform my check, when the application is ready but has not yet started.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationReadyListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        if(!checkConsistency())
           throw new MyRuntimeException();
    }

}
```

3. Now my `FailureAnalyzer` gets called and handles `MyRuntimeException` and stops the application with a proper message.

```
@Component
public class MyRuntimeExceptionFailureAnalyzer extends AbstractFailureAnalyzer<MyRuntimeException> {

    @Override
    protected FailureAnalysis analyze(Throwable rootFailure, MyRuntimeException cause) {
        return new FailureAnalysis(buildErrorMessage(cause), buildActionMessage(cause), cause);
    }

}
```